# Rails - nested model: Can't mass-assign protected attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations, nested-attributes

I have two models, `Car` and `Manufacturer`. These models are pretty simple:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :manufacturer_id, :car_name, :descr, ...
  belongs_to :manufacturer
  ...
end
```

and

```
class Manufacturer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :url
  has_many :cars
  ...
end
```

The view (`views/cars/_form.html.haml`) with form for entering data:

```
= form_for @car do |f|
  .field
  = f.label :car_name
  = f.text_field :car_name
  ...
  = f.fields_for @manufacturer do |m|
    .field
    = m.label :name
    = m.text_field :name
    ...
```

When I send the form for saving entered information (it goes to `CarsController`), I get this error:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: manufacturer

I've tried to add the

> accepts_nested_attributes_for :manufacturer

to the `Car` model, but it didn't help me...

Where is the problem?

**EDIT:**
How I am saving data in controller:

```
@manufacturer = Manufacturer.new(params[:car][:manufacturer])
@car = @manufacturer.cars.build(params[:car])
```

**EDIT2:**
Data from log:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"4vcF5NV8D91DkxpCsqCzfbf05sOYsm7ssxZvPa3+kXo=",
 "car"=>{"car_name"=>"...",
 "descr"=>"...",
 "categroy_ids"=>["2",
 "3",
 "4"],
 "manufacturer"=>{"name"=>"Company",
 "url"=>"..."}},
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "id"=>"..."}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your `params[:car]` contains `manufacturer` attributes.. Try this:  `@manufacturer = Manufacturer.new(params[:car].delete(:manufacturer)); @car = @manufacturer.cars.build(params[:car])`

Comment: While @codeit is spot on, you may want to look at `accepts_nested_attributes` for this purpose.

Comment: codeit - thanks, but - how to update yet the `update` action? Saving of a new item is working well, but getting the same error while updating data...

Comment: @user984621 If you have `has_many` relation you should create cars in `manufactures_controller` is right way to do. Here you are creating things like `has_one` relation.

Comment: @user984621 same way you have to do. can you post your update action??

Comment: at the moment, there is just `@car = Car.find(params[:id])` with `@car.update_attributes(params[:car])` - not sure how to connect with `manufacturers`

Comment: You are doing things in other way. Thats why creating problem. Still ok, what do you have in `edit` method? Can you paste the `params` from log when you call `update` action??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27029/discussion-between-codeit-and-user984621)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your params[:car] contains manufacturer attributes.. Try this:

```
@manufacturer = Manufacturer.new(params[:car].delete(:manufacturer)) 
@car = @manufacturer.cars.build(params[:car])
```

You are not making use of `has_many` relation by doing this way. You can go through [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast)

Comment: Thank you man very much for your help as here as on the chat!

Answer (score 2):

Can you save manufacturer through car?

Add to **Car** model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :manufacturer
```

Add **manufacturer_attributes** among other Car attributes to **attr_accessible** call in Car model:

```
attr_accessible :manufacturer_attributes, :car_name, :descr, ...
```

Save it in your controller action(standard way) something like this:

```
def create
  @car = Car.new(params[:car])
  if @car.save
    redirect_to @car
  else
    render :new
 end
end
```

Make sure that everything you are sending in **manufacturer_attributes** hash is white listed with attr_accessible call in Manufacturer model(:name, :url etc..).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

> attr_accessible :manufacturer_id, :car_name, :descr, :manufacturer_attributtes

in car the model. Don't bother with @manufacturer in your saving method in the car controller it is taken care of.

You should read this : [Active Record Nested Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

I hope it helped.